# Can't run Startup form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

As usual, I change the startup form under Application tab. At this time, it doesn't run my selected Startup form. Whatever I set to any forms or even excluding that form, it still runs the same form. Why does it happen?

Comment: What is the name of the form (new Form1()) in the program.cs static main method?

Comment: For vb.net project, will i check it Application.myapp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting .pdb file in debug directory and start with Build > Clean [Your SolutionName]

Comment: I also did your way. The problem was still there. And then I changed the Compile path to bin\Debug\, clean Solution and build it again. It worked. I always set this path to bin\Release. At this time, why did it happen? Thank you, regexhacks and Ira.

Comment: I don't have satisfying reason but this happened a few times with me, and deleting .pdb helped, I think the problem could the corrupted debug database (.pdb file).

Answer (score 3):

Check the `<MainForm>` element in `<project>\My Project\Application.myapp`.

If it's still not working right then check the code in `<project>\My Project\Application.Designer.vb` and look at the sub `OnCreateMainForm`. This is where the form is assigned to the main form property of the application.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
    Me.MainForm = Global.<ApplicationName>.<FormName>
End Sub
```

Comment: Let say that frmA is that I wanna run and frmB is the wrong startup form. So, in <MainForm>, it is "frmA". However, frmB is appeared at run time. :(

Comment: In this OnCreateMainForm(), it shows Me.MainForm = Global.<ApplicationName>.frmA.

Answer (score 2):

Just rebuilding the project will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the \bin and \obj directories. Then clean & rebuild.